# Flask: unable to display dictionary in Jinja html template

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am a newbee learning Flask and am trying to figure out how to pass data back and forth in my small app. 
The code below returns the error "Error code: Unhandled Exception" when a valid move is played and I really can't figure out what is wrong? (the other two options work fine.)

py code:
    theBoard = [{1:' ', 2:' ', 3:' ', 4: ' ', 5:' ', 6: ' ', 7:' ', 8:' ', 9:'       '}]

```
@app.route('/test', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x = request.form['move']
        move = int(x)
        valid_moves = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        if move not in valid_moves:
            return 'you did not specify a valid move, please try again!'
        elif theBoard[move] != ' ':
            return 'you can not play that space, it is taken'
        else:
            theBoard[move] = 'X'
            return render_template("test2.html", theBoard=theBoard)

    return render_template("test.html")
```

html code:

```
<table>
{% for key, value in theBoard.iteritems() %}
<h1>Key: {{key}}</h1>
<h2>Value: {{value}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Something went wrong with my indentation. the first code: theBoard = [{1:' ', 2:' ', 3:' ', 4: ' ', 5:' ', 6: ' ', 7:' ', 8:' ', 9:' '}] is part of the .py file

Comment: I found the following in the errorlog: File "/home/majaokholm/mysite/flask_app.py", line 19, in test
    elif theBoard[move] != ' ':
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: it was there all along, I just found it now

Comment: did this error occur with your original code, or with the code updated with my suggestion?

Comment: when it is a dict, there is no reason saying IndexError, I think

Comment: @LeiShi  
it was there all along, I just found it now

Answer (score 0):

theBoard is a list, while in test() as well as the html template you treat it as a dict. Replace first line with below code and see whether it works.

```
theBoard = {1:' ', 2:' ', 3:' ', 4: ' ', 5:' ', 6: ' ', 7:' ', 8:' ', 9:' '}
```

Comment: Nope unfortunately it does not work either.  I found the following in the error log:File "/home/majaokholm/mysite/flask_app.py", line 19, in test elif theBoard[move] != ' ': IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: as as comment in your question (sorry for inappropriately placing the comments), please try with changing theBoard to a dict, and then report your finding.

Comment: the log item might be generated when you run your previous code